# PHP find and replace, without duplicate word

Tags: php

My output is wrong,  I want the output to be as follows:

```
My CCC in my category.
```

but This is the text that output :

```
My CCC in my CCCegory
```

This is the code I tried:

```
$text = "My cat in my category";
$searchVal = array("cat", "dog", "fish");
$replaceVal = array("CCC", "DDD", "FFF");
$strtext = str_replace($searchVal, $replaceVal, $text );
echo $strtext;

//output: My CCC in my CCCegory
```

Comment: If you're trying to match whole words only then add a space on each side of the search terms.  Try `$searchVal = array(" cat ", " dog ", " fish ");`

Comment: @bassxzero that would fail though if the word is at the start or end of the text to be searched, unless you pad that text with spaces first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use regular expressions and test for word boundaries.

```
<?php
        
$text = "My cat in my category";
$searchVal = array("~\bcat\b~", "~\bdog\b~", "~\bfish\b~");
$replaceVal = array("CCC", "DDD", "FFF");
$strtext = preg_replace($searchVal, $replaceVal, $text);
echo $strtext;

//output: My CCC in my category
```